# keep the state of checkbox checked/unchecked after form submit jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have some kind of checkbox within my form which is by default is checked. What I want to do is when uncheck the checkbox and click the submit button, call javascript function to change the value of checkbox and it's state too (checked/unchecked).

That's what I tried but it's not working as expected?

```
  <form action="ResultServlet" method="post" id="searchForm">
     <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 50%;float: right">
         <tr>
           <th style="text-align: left;"><label>Work List Cases:</label></th>                       
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                <input name="workListCases" id="checkbox2" checked type="checkbox" value="">
                 <label for="checkbox2"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
      <button type="submit" onclick="changeCheckBox()" style="font-weight: bold;background-color: #F0F1F2" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>                        
  </form>
```

**js Function:**

```
 function changeCheckBox (){
           if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked')){
                $("#checkbox2").val("true");
                $('#checkbox2').attr('checked', false);
            }
            else {
                $('#checkbox2').attr('checked', true);
                $("#checkbox2").val("true");
            }
        }
```

Excuse my question if it seems tedious I am still new to jquery.

Answer (score 1):

By default your check box `value =""`...

Why value `"true"` or `"false"`?

Try it:

```
function changeCheckBox (){
           if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked')){
                $('#checkbox2').attr('checked', false);  //jquery <1.6
                $('#checkbox2').removeAttr('checked');
                $('#checkbox2').prop('checked', false); //jquery >1.6
                $('#checkbox2').removeProp('checked');
            }
            else {
                $('#checkbox2').attr('checked', true);
                $('#checkbox2').prop('checked', true);
            }
}
```